# IOAuth.IO Integration with Ionic/Angular Hybrid App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, oauth, ionic-framework

I am having a really difficult time getting the cordova plugin authored by OAuth.io (https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap) to work within the an ionic phone build. Everything is setup based off of the desktop version of the JS file they provide, wrapped in an Angular service for ease of unit testing, with another factory handling the actual flow of login/logout etc...

The issue I am running into is that now after switching to the plugin version and removing the referenced JS version, nothing works any longer. I can no longer pull up the facebook login page, nor have the global object 'OAuth' recognized outside of the injected service.  The furthest I got in troubleshooting the issue is that the OAuth object is created, at least initially as I can log out the object, but anything after that does not appear to be recognized.

My web (working) version of code example is on plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/B4HdkkBKDP3Xv2riQGui?p=preview

Any thoughts on further troubleshooting or if there is another way of accomplishing this goal would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We just published the version `0.2.0` of the OAuth.io Cordova/Phonegap SDK, which fixes the issue with Ionic.

Now you should be able to use the cordova plugin in a ionic app without any trouble, like this:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap
```

This version also contains features that were missing from the sdk, like the cache and the unified user info method.

You can get more information about all this on our github page:

https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I saw that a few hours after reviewing the question again, works quite well!