# Cannot find hostname in file:/// error when using Ionic and OAuth.io

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, oauth.io

I am using Ionic and Oauth.io to perform authentication. If I run `ionic serve` and include the `outh.js` file in my index everything works good from the browser.

But when I run `ionic run ios` or install the app in android, I get the following error when I press the auth button (the one that suppose to execute `OAuth.popup`

[image: The unexpected error]

I do not know what to do, until now I have checked the following:

1. In config.xml I have access, allow-intent and allow-navigation full permisive
2. I have installed and re-installed the plugin `ionic plugin add https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap.git`
3. I tried to run the native app without the inclusion of the oauth.js file and everything breaks.
4. Using current versions up to date.
5. I am new to Ionic, so I don't know how to debug the device-running app or simulator.
6. Could be similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622086/ioauth-io-integration-with-ionic-angular-hybrid-app) but not exactly .

Your advices will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out reading some posts. The OAuth initialization and references should be done after the device is ready, so it is best to put the initialize in this block:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  // ...
  if(typeof window.OAuth !== 'undefined'){
    $rootScope.OAuth = window.OAuth;
    $rootScope.OAuth.initialize('XXX');
  }
  else{
    console.log("plugin not loaded, this is running in a browser");
    $.getScript( "lib/oauth.js", function() {
      $rootScope.OAuth = OAuth;
      $rootScope.OAuth.initialize('XXX');
    });

  }
});
```

Now, if the plugin is loaded it initializes the window.OAuth object, else the app is running in browser, so I have to include the oauth.js file. Also I assigned the OAuth to the $rootScope for quick access.

Hope this helps anyone.